# How do I get an arbitrary local axis from a quaternion?

Tags: c++, 3d, rotation, directx, quaternions

In a 3D coordinate system to get the local x, y or z axis in world space I create a matrix from the quaternion and then extract the respective columns. But how do I get an arbitrary local axis? Say I need to get the local (0.7, 0.7, 0) in world space.

As a reference here's the C++ code I use to get the local X axis:

```
inline Matrix Matrix::CreateFromQuaternion( const Quaternion& rotation )
{
    using namespace DirectX;
    Matrix R;
    XMVECTOR quatv = XMLoadFloat4( &rotation );
    XMStoreFloat4x4( &R, XMMatrixRotationQuaternion( quatv ) );
    return R;
}

inline vec3 GetAxisX(const quat& rotation)
{
    Matrix M = Matrix::CreateFromQuaternion(rotation);
    return{ M(0, 0), M(1, 0), M(2, 0) };
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create a vector v = (0.7, 0.7, 0, 0) and do v' = v * M

Comment: @MarioDekena Yeah, that would work. Where was my head?